# When do I give commands without using the imperative tense?

Tags: grammaire, impératif

I've noticed in French that sometimes to give commands, they won't use the imperative. For example in the Oxford-Hachette dictionary, they have an example sentence; « tu ne vas pas en faire un drame! » which they translate as "Don't make a scene about it!"

So I was wondering if someone could explain when French people prefer to give commands not using the imperative tense and what effects that may have on the sentence.

Comment: Well, I disagree 100% with that translation, which, for me would be: You aren't going to make a scene, are you? It is simply not imperative in French. –

Comment: In English, imperatives can also be affirmatives: You're tidying up your room. can be a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the tone associated with the exclamation mark, using the indicative is more like giving hints to someone, similar to a film director telling an actor what he expect them to do and how before shooting a scene.

With an exclamation mark, it is indeed equivalent to an imperative, possibly slightly stronger:

> *— Tu ranges ta chambre !* (Tidy-up your room!)
> *— Range ta chambre !*

The Oxford-Hachette example is softer, more like "Let's not make a scene about it!"

Comment: @Lambie I have no doubt they can. The question is about French though.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *Range ta chambre !* ?

Comment: @psmears Yes, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the present tense for softened commands, as jlliagre explained, there's another way to give commands without the imperative (which is a mood, not a tense, by the way).

The infinitive is used to [give commands impersonally](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/impersonal-orders/), such as in recipes, instruction manuals, and warning signs.

> *Ajouter une pincée de sel.* (Add a pinch of salt.)
> *Attacher la ceinture de sécurité* (Put on your seat belt)

When it's a negative command, *ne pas* precedes the infinitive:

> *Ne pas ouvrir la fenêtre* (Do not open the window)

Comment: None of those are used in spoken French though directed at individuals. Those are written in cookbooks or on signs.